# node-gyp build error while running npm install in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

[image]I took a frontend project repo which is built on reactjs & WHILE I run `npm i` command it is giving me whole bunch of error.

1. I tried deleting `package.lock.json` file & again run the command
2. I tried by doing npm update
3. I tried `npm i --force` & `npm update --force`
   But same error is giving ..

### update

I forcely cache cleaned using this command `npm cache clean -f`. After that I again run `npm i`.. now giviing this error...

> 0 verbose cli [ 
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.11.1/bin/node', 
> 0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm', 
> 0 verbose cli   'i' 
> 0 verbose cli ] 
> 1 info using npm@8.1.2 
> 2 info using node@v16.11.1 
> 3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms 
> 4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms 
> 5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms 
> 6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms 
> 7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms 
> 8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms 
> 9 timing config:load:file:/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/private_project/xyzvara/to-let/.npmrc Completed in 1ms 
> 10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms 
> 11 timing config:load:file:/Users/macbookpro/.npmrc Completed in 0ms 
> 12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms 
> 13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms 
> 14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms 
> 15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms 
> 16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms 
> 17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms 
> 18 timing config:load Completed in 11ms 
> 19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms 
> 20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 3ms 
> 21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms 
> 22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms 
> 23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms 
> 24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms 
> 25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms 
> 26 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms 
> 27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms 
> 28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms 
> 29 timing idealTree:init Completed in 19ms 
> 30 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms 
> 31 silly idealTree buildDeps 
> 32 silly fetch manifest @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic@^25.0.0 
> 33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor%2fckeditor5-build-classic 2340ms (cache miss) 
> 34 silly fetch manifest @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@^3.0.2 
> 35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor%2fckeditor5-react 2069ms (cache miss) 
> 36 silly fetch manifest react@^16.14.0 
> 37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 905ms (cache miss) 
> 38 silly fetch manifest @hookform/devtools@^3.1.0 
> 39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@hookform%2fdevtools 1461ms (cache miss) 
> 40 silly fetch manifest react@>=17.0.2 
> 41 timing idealTree Completed in 6832ms 
> 42 timing command:install Completed in 6858ms 
> 43 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree 
> 43 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1356:25) 
> 43 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1322:34) 
> 43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:930:11) 
> 43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:216:7) 
> 43 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1) 
> 43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:149:5) 
> 43 verbose stack     at async Install.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:170:5) 
> 44 verbose cwd /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/private_project/xyzvara/to-let 
> 45 verbose Darwin 20.3.0 
> 46 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.11.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" 
> 47 verbose node v16.11.1 
> 48 verbose npm  v8.1.2 
> 49 error code ERESOLVE 
> 50 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree 
> 51 error 
> 52 error While resolving: [1mtolet[22m@[1m0.1.0[22m 
> 52 error Found: [1mreact[22m@[1m16.14.0[22m[2m[22m 
> 52 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m 
> 52 error   [1mreact[22m@"[1m^16.14.0[22m" from the root project 
> 52 error 
> 52 error Could not resolve dependency: 
> 52 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m>=17.0.2[22m" from [1m@hookform/devtools[22m@[1m3.1.0[22m[2m[22m 
> 52 error [2mnode_modules/@hookform/devtools[22m 
> 52 error   [1m@hookform/devtools[22m@"[1m^3.1.0[22m" from the root project 
> 52 error 
> 52 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
> 52 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
> 52 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. 
> 52 error 
> 52 error See /Users/macbookpro/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report. 
> 53 verbose exit 1

### update 2

I encountered an error that telling network error. So, to faster loading speed I installed `yarn` & run `yarn install`. After that strangely It installed node modules that was not happening while I was using `npm` . After that while tried to run the project It was giving node-sass error. so I did `npm audit fix -f`. but, It didn't fix all error but if I run command to start the project it is now running without giving error. Very strange , I don't have any perfect answer of this behaviour.

Comment: We had a similar issue where our version of Node was incompatible with node-sass.   What version of node-sass are you on?

Comment: `"node-sass": "^4.14.1"` .. 
but it's my own project. I just pushed it into my repo & changed my device . That's why I had to clone the project & run npm installation. While I worked my previous device there was not this kind of problem . Is that really for node-sass?

Comment: I think so, this line alludes to it:

     13106 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/private_project/xyzvara/to-let/node_modules/node-sass

Try upgrading to node-sass 6.0

Comment: I `forcely cache cleaned` then run `npm i` command . After that I am having new error...
i add the error in my question

Answer (score 1):

### update 2

I encountered an error that telling network error. So, to faster loading speed I installed `yarn` & run `yarn install`. After that strangely It installed node modules that was not happening while I was using `npm` . After that while tried to run the project It was giving node-sass error. so I did `npm audit fix -f`. but, It didn't fix all error but if I run command to start the project it is now running without giving error. Very strange , I don't have any perfect answer of this behaviour.